# How to show a string once you submit a form in a page reloading the page?

Tags: forms, 8

I need to create a page with a form and once you enter some values in the form and send it make some calculations and show a string under the form. Something like this image:

[image]

I know [how to create a page with a form inside and I know how to show a message](https://www.velir.com/blog/2016/01/04/technical-guide-drupal-8-forms) but in this case I need to show the string (message) under the form.

So, how to show a string once you submit a form in a page reloading the page?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'without ajax' - do you mean you want the page to reload after form submission, and show the value underneath? Or you want to do it with javascript, but not requiring a submission to the server?

Comment: @Jaypan I update the question, is reloading the page, thanks

Comment: Still you have it wrong, ajax won't reload the page, if you do it without Ajax it will reload the page

Comment: @DarkteK I make another update, I need reloading the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the code to calculate and display the result in the form build

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
     $form['number1'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
    );
    $form['number2'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
    );

    $form['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Sum'),
    );

    $values = $form_state->getValues();
    if (!empty($values)) {
      $result = $values['number1'] + $values['number2'];
      $form['result'] = ['#markup' => '<p>' . $result . '</p>'];
    }

    return $form;
  }
```

So that the result can be included in the form rebuild when the input values are filled in.

In submit request a rebuild:

```
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form_state->setRebuild();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I made some changes in your code and I add the final code because I think is better for other people. Have a great day!