# Send form result back to twig

Tags: 8, forms

I created a module for searching values from external databases. My controller creates a form and send it to the custom twig page of my module.

The controller method that creates the form and send the data to the twig template looks like:

```
 public function customSearchPage($query, $results)
    {
         $searchForm = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\movies\Form\SearchForm');

        $searchForm['searchQuery']['#value'] = $query;

        return [ 
            '#theme' => 'insert_movie_page',
            '#form' => $searchForm,
            '#query' => $query,
            '#results' => $results,
        ];
    }
```

Now I created a Form using the Drupal 8 Form API. The submitForm method will send the inserted data to a compute class and gets a resultset back (array with multiple model objects). Now I need to send the resultset back to the twig template to show the results to the users. How can I achieve this behaviour?

SubmitForm method looks like:

```
 public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

      $search = $form_state->getValue('searchQuery');

      $SearchController = new SearchController;
      $results = $SearchController->searchMovies($search);
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In submit you have two choices.

**Rebuild**

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $form_state->setRebuild();
}
```

The form and the twig template the form is wrapped in will be rebuilt and you can display the result.

This is a great question from @AdrianCidAlmaguer to demonstrate how this works with a basic example how to display the sum of two numbers: [How to show a string once you submit a form in a page reloading the page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223780/how-to-show-a-string-once-you-submit-a-form-in-a-page-reloading-the-page)

**Redirect**

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $form_state->setRedirect($route_name, $route_parameters, $options);
}
```

You redirect to a new page and can display the result there.

Comment: How to send the array with objects using the redirect way? I don't want to markup the result already in the form because of the complexity and is better to place that in twig.

Comment: For simple cases you can add query parameters to the route. For complex cases you use most times a session. - But for anonymous users the rebuild is far more efficient and this is probably the better approach, because drupal has a temp store for the form data and you can build very complex things by just rebuilding a form again and again.

Comment: The page is only visible for authenticated users. So I can use session vars for this. Tnx