# How to add two extra buttons in a form to do extra actions with form data

Tags: forms

I have a simple custom form with 3 submit buttons - one that calls the default hook_form_submit and generates a table. The submit as the rebuild as TRUE:

```
$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
```

that shows the complete form with the 3 buttons and the tables.

I need the 2 extra buttons to call different functions but I need inputs from the form itself or the table array.

At the moment, with the code I have, I can't access the form data and also, the tables created by the main submit disappear when I click the 2 extra buttons.

My code:

```
function MYMOUDLE_form($form, &$form_state) {
    $form['container']['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t("Submit Form"),  
    );

    $form['container']['export_1'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t("Export - 1"),
        '#submit' => array('MYMOUDLE_export_1'),
    );

    $form['container']['export_2'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t("Export - 2"),
        '#submit' => array('MYMOUDLE_export_2'),
    );

    return $form;
}

function MYMOUDLE_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    # do my stuff - generate tables
}

function MYMOUDLE_export_1($form, $form_values) {
    dpm($form_values);
    $someData1 = MYMODULE_handleFormData1($formValue1, $formValue2, $formValue3);
    drupal_set_message('Action for export 1 was done successfully.');
}

function MYMOUDLE_export_2($form, $form_values) {
    dpm($form_values);
    $someData2 = MYMODULE_handleFormData2($formValue1, $formValue2, $formValue3);
    drupal_set_message('Action for export 2 was done successfully.');
}
```

Comment: You probably need to rebuild the form, not redirect. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224917/send-form-result-back-to-twig

Comment: Sorry. I have redirect in my submit. $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;

Comment: OK, if you rebuild the form you should see the form data when rebuilding the form. By the way you can check in $form_state the triggering element so that you know which button was pressed before rebuilding.

Comment: I added $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE; to the MYMOUDLE_export_1 and MYMOUDLE_export_2 and changed the arguments to "$form, &$form_state". That solved it. I now have access to the form_state and the form is completely rebuilt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than write submit function for each button use *$form_state['triggering_element'].* This will provide you the which button is clicked with form data in default hook_form_submit